# Testing movie with Flash IDE fails to load file from localhost

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash, flash-cs4

I'm just wondering if anybody can help me with my simple but frustrating problem.

I have created an SWF that loads an XML file from http://localhost/flash/Projects/MEL/Quiz/Quiz/bin/xml/quiz.xml, but I get this error when running the movie using Test Movie in the Flash IDE.

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/flash/Projects/MEL/Quiz/Quiz/bin/xml/quiz.xml
    at Main/loadConfig()[D:\www\webroot\flash\Projects\MEL\Quiz\Quiz\src\Main.as:126]
    at Main/configLoadError()[D:\www\webroot\flash\Projects\MEL\Quiz\Quiz\src\Main.as:143]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

The error I get if I handle the exception is:

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/flash/Projects/MEL/Quiz/Quiz/bin/xml/quiz.xml"]
```

Trouble is running the SWF in a browser locally does work, it only throws these errors in the Flash IDE.

I have tried a adding wildcard crossdomain.xml file in my root web directory and setting the SWF publish properties for local playback security to Allow network only, but neither of these have solved my problem.

I know Windows 7 handles localhost name resolution differently compared to previous versions of Windows but I have even added `127.0.0.1 localhost` to my hosts file to no avail.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Comment: can you find out more about the unhandled error ? like try { .. }catch(e) { trace(e);} ?  It's weird because it doesnt say it can't find the file.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the error I am getting when handling the exception to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved my problem, and now I feel stupid.

For some reason Comodo Firewall was blocking the Flash IDE on any IP and any port. The firewall usually asks me to allow or deny a connection, however in this case it didn't so I never gave the firewall a thought.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: thank you very much ... for the soln. and for entering  the chat zone :D.. solved my problem which was same as yours..thanks a lot. i had eset smart security firewall on. i turned it off.. and all started working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a relative path to the file. Should work on both scenarios, flash IDE and browser.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in my original question that I used to use relative paths, which work fine. However I have had to switch it to absolute paths due to the XML being generated via PHP.

Using a relative path in the Flash IDE to a dynamic PHP file just loads the PHP code and not the parsed XML results that I require.

Thanks anyway.