# FLASH as3 not able to identify localhost php web address

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I am trying to retrieve mysql data using php(products.php) and return the data in xml format to ADobe flash as3; but i am getting following error.

```
Error opening URL 'http://localhost/Flash/player/products.php'
```

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/Flash/player/products.php at php_mysql3_as3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Please any suggestion or help why flash is not identifying the http://localhost/Flash/player/products.php addres. i have WAMP installed; which works fine as i have many other php projects working here.

### Thanks in advance for help and suggestion.

THe following is my php code

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("test");

$query = "select * from products";
$results = mysql_query($query);


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'." \n";
echo"<GALLERY>\n";
$cnt=0;
while($line=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    echo '<IMAGE TITLE="'.$cnt.'">'.$line['product'].'</IMAGE>'." \n";
    $cnt++;
}

echo "</GALLERY>\n";

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

the php file is located at c:\wamp\www\Flash\player\products.php

---

below is my AS3 flash code

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

//myLoader.load(new URLRequest("c:\\wamp\\www\\Flash\\player\\products2.xml"));
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/Flash/player/products.php"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);


function processXML(evt:Event):void {

myXML = new XML(evt.target.data);
for (var i:int = 0; i<myXML.*.length(); i++){
trace("My image number is " + (i+1) + ", it's title is " + myXML.IMAGE[i].@TITLE + " and it's URL is " + myXML.IMAGE[i]);
};
//trace("data: " + myLoader.data);;
}
```

Comment: Does the same URL work if you use it in your browser? Remember that Apache is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In chat it turned out the problem was a firewall.

Here is another related question:

[Testing movie with Flash IDE fails to load file from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336150/testing-movie-with-flash-ide-fails-to-load-file-from-localhost)

Comment: was a long ride, thanks to davgothic who wrote his solution down.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible:

1. Your movie runs in the local realm, and you are trying to load a network resource (i guess this will be the case). In that case you need to add the compile flag: `-use-network=true`
2. The php file does not exist.

You always need to catch the URLLoader events:

```
dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

to see what happened!

See these event handlers in action: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: thanks for reply . my .fla file is at c:\wamp\www\Flash\player\test.fla location  AND php file is c:\wamp\www\Flash\player\products.php location. and i am running WAMP server on the same system. sorry, i didnt get your first point.

Comment: What does `trace(Security.sandboxType)` output?

Comment: Please attach the described listeners to your `myLoader` and catch the error event: `trace (event);` Flash complain currently about a not handled IO Error, so perhaps and most probably your php file does is not accessible on your localhost.

Comment: i tried loading the php file loacally in browser. it echoes proper output. php mysql dont have problem, been working on it from several years. but am new to flash :( added 
var dispatcher:CustomDispatcher = new CustomDispatcher();
dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);   and now its giving error for dispatcher

Comment: @ParagRedkar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2003/discussion-between-jens-struwe-and-parag-redkar)